# Unable to run Mongo shell (Mac)

Tags: mongodb, terminal, homebrew, locomotivecms

I'm new to web development and I wanted to get started with some RoR (using Locomotive CMS).

One of the things Locomotive asks for is to have Mongodb. I installed using homebrew by following this link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

It installs fine but then im not able to run it!

When I type 'mongo' on terminal I get the following output :

```
"MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: test
Mon May  6 11:12:28.927 
JavaScript execution failed: 
Error: couldn't connect to server        
127.0.0.1:27017 at   src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
exception: connect failed"
```

BACKGROUND TO HELP DEBUGGING ( on Terminal) :

1.When I type in mongod I get the following :

```
"all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"
```

Ownership of mongo.log :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 username  admin  22133 May  6 11:13 mongo.log
```

2.When I input mongod --fork I get the following :

```
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 77566
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
```

3.Typing mongod --help gives the following warning:

```
* WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
```

4.I have a folder called data (which acts as amongodb database, is this where it should be?)in root (PATH : /data)  Ownership of data folder :

```
 "drwxr-xr-x   3 username  wheel       102 Apr 23 21:38 data"
```

5.Checking if ports are free: lsof -i :27017. Ive also tried to check for a running mongo process using activity montior and found zilch!

```
No output
```

6.Ive also tried : mongo --repair. Dint help!

Ive been stuk on this for a while, I've looked at most responses on stackoverflow and searched around to find a solution to this but nothing has helped so far!

UPDATE:

When I tried to start the mongo shell, I was getting the following l
log message from mongo.log:

```
5/6/13 1:33:27.616 PM com.apple.launchd: 
(org.mongodb.mongod[79133])          
open("/private/var/log/mongodb/output.log", ...): Permission denied
```

So I did a chmod777 for the particular folder and the shell launches!

Although I still get a warning when it launches as:

```
Server has startup warnings: 
Mon May  6 13:33:27.693 [initandlisten] 
Mon May  6 13:33:27.693 [initandlisten] 
** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. 
Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
```

Any idea how I can silence these warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the information you need to determine the cause of failure you need to look in (and post for us) the output from `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` when it is trying to start.

However, the most common reason for the failure is the lack of the default database path - at `/data/db`.  Either create that folder (and don't forget to make sure your user has permission to read/write to it) or specify a different path with the `--dbpath` option.

UPDATE: as you have since found, bad permissions on the log file can cause the issue, in a similar way to bad permissions on the data path.

In terms of the warning, the information you need is here:

https://superuser.com/questions/433746/is-there-a-fix-for-the-too-many-open-files-in-system-error-on-os-x-10-7-1

It is just that though, a warning - you can run MongoDB without an issue with those limits as long as it is not under heavy load.  So, if this is a development environment, unless you plan on load testing, you should be fine

Comment: Adam, thanks for the response! I followed your advice on looking up the mongo.log and it did the trick! Seems my log file was located elsewhere and it dint have permissions (I've updated my question with my findings).Although there are still warnings! Please have a look at my updated question!